# Data from serial port only displayed when cable is unplugged

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded-linux, tty, termios

I am trying to read data from serial port sent by RS232 module using :

1. A USB - SERIAL converter
2. A C program and the lib TERMIOS (Which worked perfectly ; I can read and send data in real time).
3. A Linux environment

Now, I'm trying to do the exact same thing but using directly the serial port of my device and not the USB port.

With the same configuration (except I change the device from tty USB0 to tty mxc2 and using a RS232 cable only not the USB - SERIAL converter). **I can't get the data but when I unplug the RS232 cable, all the data I try to read is received and printed to the terminal.**

I also tried to use stty directly to read  (thinking it was a C problem) but I get the same result (I unplug the RS232 cable & the data is read)

I can not explain why there is a delta between using  USB - RS232 converter and using only RS232 cable.

```
//configuration of TERMIOS : 
    
tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSTOPB | CRTSCTS); /* only need 1 stop bit  & no hardware flowcontrol */

/* setup for non-canonical mode */
tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);

tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

//trying to read with termios :

 retlen = read(fd,&tmp_buff,1);
    if (retlen > 0) 
        printf("%02x\n",tmp_buff);
```

here are some result and output from terminal that may help :

When the cable is plugged the data are not displayed

```
root@2021ufv6zgzg:~# ./main.exe
```

When the cable is unplugged the data are displayed

```
root@2021ufv6zgzg:~# ./main.exe 
00
fe
00
fe
00
fe
00
fe
```

Same goes with only stty, data displayed when I unplug the cable :

```
od -x < /dev/ttymxc2
0003260     fe00    fe00    fe00    fe00    fe00    fe00    fe00    fe00
```

Thank you very much for your help. Even though you can not find the solution, i'd really like to know the differences between using tty USB0 and tty mxc2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add pictures of plain text. Instead simply copy&paste your terminal output into the question. If it gets not formatted correctly, we can help you with that.

Comment: What happens before you unplug the cable? Do you read 0 bytes over and over again or are you blocked in `read` command?

Comment: @Gerhardh I dont read anything. The value return of the read function is 0 until I unplug the cable. It is then set to 1 and display BYTE by BYTE all the data that was not displayed.. thank you, i will copy paste the terminal output

Comment: Which Linux kernel module is the USB-serial converter using?

Comment: Seems like buffer problem: Pretty sure with the RS232 the buffer is empty (and then printed) after he is being unplugged, while its empty more often in USB. You may check RS232 config in the device side if possible.

Comment: You might also want to branch a GDB on your program an check where in the `read()` function your program is locked.

Comment: `tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0` means you are busy polling. It would be more conventional to use a vmin of 1, so the read blocks until a character is available. If you are on a microcomputer with one cpu this might explain why the output is not able to appear.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your answers.  @Welgriv I used GDB and my program is not locked. It simply enters the "IF" part when the the cable is unplugged, it means, the return value of read is set to 1 only when the cable is unplugged.

Comment: @meuh, while using stty (and even in other test with the C program) I set VMIN to 1. Same result everytime....

Comment: What exactly is *"my device"*?  Is it a custom board?  You also need to provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); so far you have only posted snippets of code that seem to be missing salient statements.  FYI for a properly implemented RS-232 port, the UART driver and the termios layer would be unaware of a connector/cable disconnect unless HW handshake or modem control lines are active.

Comment: *"I also tried to use stty directly to read ..."* -- That's an inaccurate description of a useless "test".  The **stty** command is not for *"reading"*, but used to "change and print terminal line settings".  You don't even seem to use the **stty** command, so there is no change whatsoever when you use the **od** command for input.  IOW you have not used any alternative termios configuration.  Instead, a worthwhile test would be trying to read using a terminal emulation program (such as **picocom** or **minicom**) on the target board.

Comment: @sawdust even though your reply was not pleasant to  read. Thank you for your help.

So, I did not post the command I used to configure the ttymxc2 with stty because I have tried many many configurations. Also, I tried with minicom aswell and got the same result.

My point using stty was to be sure that Termios or my C program was not the problem.

The device is, indeed, a custom board. Since It is gonna be hard for other people to help me with that board, I was just wondering if that could be a known problem with  tty conf, Linux or RS232.